# How do I use instafeed to show my photos with instagram?

Tags: plugins, instagram, instafeedjs

Before all my photos show up on my website. Since June 1 2016, my photos aren't showing on my website. I know that instagram change a lot of things but I don't how it works. What are steps to show up my photos again?

I went to this site for a new token. 
http://instagram.pixelunion.net

What do I have to do to make my photos show up again?
Do I have to start a submission?

This is my website 
http://braveandco.com/community

These are my settings. I have 4 tabs with different hashtags but I think I have to generate a new access token for all 4 hashtags. I did generate a new token but it's not working. I also try to change my userId to clientId.
Should I change userId to clientId?

```
var bravesMinimal = new Instafeed({
    target: 'tab1',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'bravesminimal',
    userId: XXXXXXXX,
    accessToken: 'XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    limit: 12,
    resolution: 'low_resolution',
    template: '<div class="insta-wrap"><img src="{{image}}" /><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><div class="likes-wrap"><div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></div></a></div>',
    after: function() {
        if (!this.hasNext()) {
            myButton.hide();
        }
    }
});
```